# gson.fromJson is returning null android retrofit and gson

Tags: android, retrofit, gson

I am getting null when I am converting my json error response from retrofit to an object.

JSON String:

```
{"messageType":1,"hasErrors":true,"isSuccess":false,"message":"Invalid username or password"}
```

The class I created:

```
public class ValidationContainer {


@SerializedName("messageType")
@Expose
private int MessageType;

@SerializedName("hasErrors")
@Expose
private Boolean HasErrors;

@SerializedName("isSuccess")
@Expose
private Boolean IsSuccess;

@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String Message;


public ValidationContainer() {
}

public String getMessage() {
    return Message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.Message = message;
}
```

}

My Code:

```
            public void onResponse(Call<UserDTO> call, Response<UserDTO> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    //TODO: Save response user properties to shared constants

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else if (response.code() == 400) {

                    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                    ValidationContainer container = new ValidationContainer();

                    try {
                        Log.e(Tag, response.errorBody().string());
                        container = gson.fromJson(response.errorBody().string(), ValidationContainer.class);

                        Log.e(Tag, container.getMessage());

                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        Log.e(Tag, e.getMessage());

                    }
                }
            }
```

When I log `response.errorBody().string()` I get the following:

[image]

In build.gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to change `UserDTO` to `ValidationContainer`.

Comment: @DheerubhaiBansal But I want to convert the error not the success response

Comment: kindly change your library version to `com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, based on this link: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client

```
public void onResponse(Call<UserDTO> call, Response<UserDTO> response) {

    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        //TODO: Save response user properties to shared constants

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

    } else if (response.code() == 400) {

        Converter<ResponseBody, ValidationContainer> converter =
                retrofit.responseBodyConverter(ValidationContainer.class, new Annotation[0]);

        try {
            ValidationContainer error = converter.convert(response.errorBody());

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(Tag, e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please post error message present in log initially i thought you have to implements Serializable interface

```
public class ValidationContainer implements Serializable {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please paste actual code because I don't think gson parsing require any IO exception for parsing as I can see you are using it.

also try after removing `if (response.code() == 400)`

Comment: what do you mean post the actual code - the code posted in the question is the actual code